# Menu inside popup

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, menu

I have a top main menu visible on all my pages.

The first part of the menu contains 4 inputs to set the start date + hour (2 inputs) and the end date + hour (2 inputs). This defines my period.

The second part of the menu is 8 dropdowns with a total of 30 options. They are grouped into a certain pattern determined by the former developer and I cannot really give them a name. They all have the first option pre-selected. Each option will show some data (present between the range selected) on a map just below the menu.

After selection, the dates, hours and one option - A "validate" button appears below.

[image: menu]

I would like to find the easiest way to create this menu.

## IDEA

Only show the 4 inputs aligned on 1 line and one button on the second line which would be "Select data" or "Select option".

This button will open a popup with a search bar and all the options as a small button. The user will then have a general view of all the option and easily find what he needs thanks to the search bar. After clicking on the option, the popup closes and the data are shown

[image: FutureMenu]

Is it a good way to show the menu?

User should have the possibility to only edit the dates or to keep the dates and update the option

Comment: The idea here seems muddy. What is the goal of this application? What is the context? What does the menu have to do with this form?

Comment: @invot Hey thanks for the extra bump ! Finally the design was totally changed and I do not use this layout anymore. Thanks for trying to help me !

Comment: @Weedoze Each dropdown has 30 options?

Comment: @NB4 Thanks for helping me but the client changed his mind and this menu is no more used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help !

Unfortunately the client changed his mind and decided to totally changed the menu.

I did not use a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to complicate things. Content expansion is a great approach in situations like yours.

It's like if you have a search bar and an "advanced search" button that expands the form revealing additional search options. No additional windows or modals are required here.

**Example figure**

[image]

**Example code**

http://jsfiddle.net/zqsfx/

Comment: I dont understand... Thus I keep my menu and add an "advanced search" button ? Where ? Could you please do a quick draw ?

Comment: @Weedoze added and example figure and an actual example.

Comment: I dont really like this solution... + User should be able to only edit the inputs without re-selecting the options (Question edited) sorry

Comment: Disable the other fields then. What is stopping you from decreasing the number of options?

Comment: Disable the fields ? Decreasing the number of options ? What ?

Comment: You want to let the user to only edit dates, right? What is stopping you from only allowing to edit the dates?

Comment: In your case, user should always click on "change options" and select or re-select the option. I should be able to edit inputs then click on "Validate" somewhere

Comment: @Weedoze I have edited the image for you.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have 30 options.. It can easily take all the page or more if I should display everything below the inputs

Comment: But you said that user can only edit the date.. Why would you display all 30 options if only a couple of them can be edited?

Comment: The first time user should fill in the 4 inputs and select 1 option from the 30 available. After that, user can either change the dates (inputs) and keep the option OR he can keep the dates but change the option OR change both

Comment: Do you have a live example of what kind of mess is going on there? 30 options to choose from in one page is absurd already. Can we see that?

Comment: See in my question the first image is my menu for the moment. As I explained, there is 8 dropdown each containing different options. If I resume all this options, there is a total of 30. User must select one option from one of the dropdown

Comment: Can you give more details on what are the options? And how are they currently arranged into 8 drop-downs. And can I actually see what it looks like in real life?

Comment: The 8 dropdown were arranged by an ex-developper and I cannot really understand how he did it. All options represent either a link to another page or a kind of data to show on the map placed below the menu

Comment: @Weedoze are you able to show it to us?

Comment: Yes, it is the first image in my question

Comment: @Weedoze sorry, I meant a working example